# Is there a maximum length of pdf file QGIS composer can plot?

Tags: qgis, pdf, print-composer

In QGIS 2.4 is there a maximum dimension in milimeters composer can produce while exporting to pdf?
Trying to produce a 3000 x 900 mm or 2800 x 900 mm map. The QGIS composer displays all the map area but everytime i export it to pdf, the map gets cut at about 2780 mm displaying white space.

Comment: What DPI value do you use? I wonder if it happens to make 14400 pixels for the width. Then it could have something to do with http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/What-is-the-maximum-page-size-for-PDF-in-iText-td2150839.html and http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5412

Comment: What if you print the map as raster under the composition tab.

Comment: What operating system are you using? 64 bit builds of QGIS will handle much larger composition exports than 32 bit builds.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't comment or login using the account i started the topic so I am posting this as an answer. Your comments gave me ground to some testing and it seems that the problem is partly solved.
For the record I'm using the 64 bit version. All this time I was exporting a 3000 x 900 mm map with "print as raster" option selected at 300 dpi.
So 300 dpi gives me a cut map, 350 dpi cuts it even more, 600 dpi gives me a white map (nothing is exported), 400 dpi - same as 600. Changing it to 100 dpi seem to solved the problem - it exported whole map.
Unselecting the "print as raster" option also gave good results but only when there are no raster layers on. Tried it with a full raster coverage plus some vectors and the generating time was very long, but the map was whole.
Also raster at 100 dpi was 24 mb while vector was 540 mb. So it's ether low quality or long waits + huge files.